# Dynamically loading html form with jQuery doesn't bring <select> values

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm running Chrome 34 and developing a little app using XAMPP on my localhost. Upon clicking a span of text, I have jQuery grabbing a snippet of HTML using `.load(path/file.stub.php)`. What's happening is that the form shows up on the page, labels and all, except that the `option` values in the `select` dropdown list aren't appearing. They are static and present in the code snippet being loaded.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#getStarted").on("click", function() {

        //Render create player form in content div
        $("#content").load("stubs/createPlayerForm.stub.php");
    });

});
```

I'm confused about why this is happening and haven't had much luck Googling the issue since it's difficult to know how to phrase it. Thanks in advance for reading.

EDIT: Using jQuery 1.11.0 from Google Hosted Libraries.

Comment: is your server side php file returning full html? like <option></option>

Comment: Show your stubs/createPlayerForm.stub.php

Comment: I won't paste the entire thing, but it's basically this (and the tags are working if this pasted into a static HTML file):
`<form id="foo" action="bar.php">`
  `<label for="foo2">Foo2: </label><select id="foo2" name="foo2"><option name="bar2" value="Bar 2">Bar 2</option><input type="submit"/></select></form>`

Comment: What if you inspect SELECT element once rendered client side? Is there any OPTION as content?

Comment: @A. Wolff - Interestingly the .load() is bringing in `<select>` but it's closing it right away so that the option values, which are there, aren't attached! Is this a known issue?

Comment: Looks like you are not rendering valid HTML markup. Now we need to see your relevant code server side

Comment: My apologies - there was an errant `/>` on the first select tag. It rendered fine when brought up statically, but the `.load()` expanded it into a full-blown closing tag, which then made the `<option>` tags useless.

Comment: @armadadrive Ya, that's explain it, glad your issue is fixed ;)

Comment: Funny how it worked just fine in the context of a static page.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, there was an errant `/` at the end of the opening `<select>` tag, e.g. `<select name="foo" id="foo" />`

Although this snippet rendered fine in Chrome 34 when put on a static HTML page, the jQuery `.load()` function turned this into: `<select name="foo" id="foo"></select>` which obviously did **not** render correctly as it meant the `<option>` values below it were not properly attached to the `select` element.